# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, core-foundation, nsdecimalnumber, objectiveresource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128316/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Can anyone tell me what is going on in this error code? Man apple is cryptic. I have just made a call via ObjectiveResource to data I know is fine.

```
-[NSDecimalNumber allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c671f0
2011-03-02 02:07:56.169 Mobile[13839:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c671f0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0133bbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014905c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0133d6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x012ad366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x012acf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Mobile                      0x00013aa5 +[NSObject(JSONSerializableSupport) deserializeJSON:] + 832
    6   Mobile                      0x000138ad +[NSObject(JSONSerializableSupport) deserializeJSON:] + 328
    7   Mobile                      0x00012f0e +[NSObject(JSONSerializableSupport) fromJSONData:] + 161
    8   Mobile                      0x0000c8fa +[NSObject(ObjectiveResource) findAllRemoteWithResponse:] + 336
    9   Mobile                      0x0000c933 +[NSObject(ObjectiveResource) findAllRemote] + 43
    10  Mobile                      0x00004732 -[AllTableViewController refresh] + 103
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed `NSDecimalNumber` does not respond to `allKeys` selector and that causes a crash.

That may happen because the instance of NSDictionary, the intended message responder was prematurely deallocated for some reason (lack of retain?) and its address in memory got occupied by `NSDecimalNumber` instance that gets that wrong message.

So to fix that problem try locating the line that message and check if everything is ok with memory management in that code.

Comment: And if it is, then you need to find where it isn't, beacuse the memory management certainly is not OK *somewhere*. Instruments's Zombies template will help nail down the culprit, as you can look over the entire retain and release history of the prematurely-deallocated object.

Answer (score 1):

You calling allKeys method on `NSDecimalNumber`,and `NSDecimalNumber` can,t use this method thats why you having a crash.

allKeys method call with `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`.

so type `where` after getting this log you get line number at there you need to edit the code.

Comment: +1.Seems to be simple type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

NSDecimalNumber does not support the method allKeys.